# ¿Qué significa que la expresión debe tener un valor constante?

Tags: c++

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
int valores[j][i], n = j - 1, x = i - 1, total = 0;
for (j = 0; j <= n; j++)
{
    system("cls");
    cout << "Renglón " << j + 1 << endl;
    for (i = 0; i <= x; i++)
    {
        cout << "Ingrese el valor " << i + 1 << endl;
        cin >> valores[j][i];
        total += valores[j][i];
    }
}
```

Pero cuando le doy a compilar me sale el [siguiente error en la primera línea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEyjz.png):

> int i
>
> la expresión debe tener un valor constante
>   el valor de variable "i" (se declara en la línea 9) no puede usarse como una constante

¿Por qué me sale ese error y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: En donde declaras las variables j y i?

Answer (score 2):

Esto ocurre porque estás definiendo un array que debe tener tamaño constante y conocido en tiempo de compilación usando variables cuyo valor *no* es conocido en tiempo de compilación.

No importa que estés declarando la variable y dándole un valor que luego no cambie (no se ve si ese es el caso en el código compartido), el compilador tendría que analizar el código y ver si los valores de `i` o `j` cambian y dónde, y en lugar de hacer eso, lo que haces es mostrarte el fallo y terminar la compilación con un error.

Quizás podrías usar extensiones del compilador para solucionar el problema, pero eso haría tu código menos portable (si cambias de compilador, tu código puede dejar de compilar de nuevo). Así que la mejor solución sería crear el array de manera dinámica usando `new` o `malloc`.

- Por ejemplo así con `new`:

  ```
  int **valores = new int*[j];
  for (int x = 0; x < j; x++)
    valores[x] = new int[i];
  ```
- o así con `malloc`:

  ```
  int **valores = (int **) malloc (j * sizeof(int *));
  for (int x = 0; x < j; x++)
    valores[x] = (int *) malloc (i * sizeof(int));
  ```

Y no te olvides de hacer un `delete` (si usas `new`) o `free` (si usas `malloc`) para liberar la memoria cuando termines de usar ese array.